# Sorting html elements

Tags: javascript, html, sorting

What would be the best way to sort following elements by data attributes, depending on option selected?

```
<select class="form-control" id="orderBy">
    <option value="0">Default</option>
    <option value="1">Price Descending</option>
    <option value="2">Price Ascending</option>
    <option value="3">Name A-Z</option>
</select>

    <div id="items">

    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center" data-name="Sticker | boltz (Foil) | Cluj-Napoca 2015" data-position="0" data-bot="2" data-coins="630" data-itemid="5538264193">
        <div class="bank_item" style="position:relative;border:2px solid black" data-name="Sticker | boltz (Foil) | Cluj-Napoca 2015" data-position="0" data-bot="2" data-coins="630" data-itemid="5538264193">
            <div class="bank_bot">#2</div>
            <div class="bank_itemprice">630 coins</div><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXQ9QVcJY8gulReQFnaFbT8goDAWlpLJwtboqCaLQhp373JIzlH7t7kwtDZwPKmMe7UxGlVv5Uni-qVrI-g3wbgqUs5MDuhJtWXbEZgNlgEOFRc/150x150">
            <div class="bank_name" style="color:white">Sticker | boltz (Foil) | Cluj-Napoca 2015</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center" data-name="Sticker | JW | Cluj-Napoca 2015" data-position="1" data-bot="1" data-coins="550" data-itemid="5649200610">
        <div class="bank_item" style="position:relative;border:2px solid black" data-name="Sticker | JW | Cluj-Napoca 2015" data-position="1" data-bot="1" data-coins="550" data-itemid="5649200610">
            <div class="bank_bot">#1</div>
            <div class="bank_itemprice">550 coins</div><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXQ9QVcJY8gulReQFnaFbT8goDAWlpLLxMZsuz2eVRmgaWbKT4a747ixdXSlKKjZe7SwD1VsMMoiLuUoo2ijAewr10sPT7nQSOp_Q/150x150">
            <div class="bank_name" style="color:white">Sticker | JW | Cluj-Napoca 2015</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center" data-name="Sticker | DreamHack | Cluj-Napoca 2015" data-position="2" data-bot="2" data-coins="550" data-itemid="5626585817">
        <div class="bank_item" style="position:relative;border:2px solid black" data-name="Sticker | DreamHack | Cluj-Napoca 2015" data-position="2" data-bot="2" data-coins="550" data-itemid="5626585817">
            <div class="bank_bot">#2</div>
            <div class="bank_itemprice">550 coins</div><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXQ9QVcJY8gulReQFnaFbT8goDXW146cwFU5uP3f1Ixi_HMcm9GuN_hwIGNk6-gYuPQwDpUu5xzj-zC99Xw0BqkpRTbClhRtg/150x150">
            <div class="bank_name" style="color:white">Sticker | DreamHack | Cluj-Napoca 2015</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 text-center" data-name="Autograph Capsule | Natus Vincere | Cluj-Napoca 2015" data-position="3" data-bot="2" data-coins="480" data-itemid="5623512673">
        <div class="bank_item" style="position:relative;border:2px solid black" data-name="Autograph Capsule | Natus Vincere | Cluj-Napoca 2015" data-position="3" data-bot="2" data-coins="480" data-itemid="5623512673">
            <div class="bank_bot">#2</div>
            <div class="bank_itemprice">480 coins</div><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fROi43Z2DAghLKwVBv_T8cwYy1vWeJW5D6orildnTlq-ga-yIkzMDvJMg2bCT9tul3AWy_EVofSmtc3pMizym/150x150">
            <div class="bank_name" style="color:white">Autograph Capsule | Natus Vincere | Cluj-Napoca 2015</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using TinySort, but however it does not work or I'm doing something wrong.

```
$('#orderBy').on('change',function(){
    var by = $(this).val();
    switch(by)
    {
        case 1: tinysort('#items .col-sm-2',{data:'coins',order:'desc'}); break;
        case 2: tinysort('#items .col-sm-2',{data:'coins',order:'asc'}); break;
        case 3: tinysort('#items .col-sm-2',{data:'name',order:'asc'}); break;
        default: tinysort('#items .col-sm-2',{data:'position',order:'asc'});
    }
});
```

Selecting any option does nothing. Is there any simple way to sort them? Thanks

EDIT:
This is how it looks at the moment:
[image]

Comment: mmm some csgo stuff going on here :D

Comment: @MattiaNocerino yes, no offtopic please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$(this).val()` is returning a **String**, not a Number.

You need to **change `1` to `"1"`** and the same in other cases in the  **`switch-case`**.

**Snippet of your code working:**

```js
$('#orderBy').on('change', function() {
  var by = $(this).val();
  switch (by) {
    case "1":
      tinysort('#items .col-sm-2', {
        data: 'coins',
        order: 'desc'
      });
      break;
    case "2":
      tinysort('#items .col-sm-2', {
        data: 'coins',
        order: 'asc'
      });
      break;
    case "3":
      tinysort('#items .col-sm-2', {
        data: 'name',
        order: 'asc'
      });
      break;
    default:
      tinysort('#items .col-sm-2', {
        data: 'position',
        order: 'asc'
      });
  }
});
```

```css
#items{
  background-color: #212121;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinysort/2.3.0/tinysort.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinysort/2.3.0/jquery.tinysort.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" id="orderBy">
  <option value="0">Default</option>
  <option value="1">Price Descending</option>
  <option value="2">Price Ascending</option>
  <option value="3">Name A-Z</option>
</select>

<div id="items">

  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center" data-name="Sticker | boltz (Foil) | Cluj-Napoca 2015" data-position="0" data-bot="2" data-coins="630" data-itemid="5538264193">
    <div class="bank_item" style="position:relative;border:2px solid black" data-name="Sticker | boltz (Foil) | Cluj-Napoca 2015" data-position="0" data-bot="2" data-coins="630" data-itemid="5538264193">
      <div class="bank_bot">#2</div>
      <div class="bank_itemprice">630 coins</div>
      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXQ9QVcJY8gulReQFnaFbT8goDAWlpLJwtboqCaLQhp373JIzlH7t7kwtDZwPKmMe7UxGlVv5Uni-qVrI-g3wbgqUs5MDuhJtWXbEZgNlgEOFRc/150x150">
      <div class="bank_name" style="color:white">Sticker | boltz (Foil) | Cluj-Napoca 2015</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center" data-name="Sticker | JW | Cluj-Napoca 2015" data-position="1" data-bot="1" data-coins="550" data-itemid="5649200610">
    <div class="bank_item" style="position:relative;border:2px solid black" data-name="Sticker | JW | Cluj-Napoca 2015" data-position="1" data-bot="1" data-coins="550" data-itemid="5649200610">
      <div class="bank_bot">#1</div>
      <div class="bank_itemprice">550 coins</div>
      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXQ9QVcJY8gulReQFnaFbT8goDAWlpLLxMZsuz2eVRmgaWbKT4a747ixdXSlKKjZe7SwD1VsMMoiLuUoo2ijAewr10sPT7nQSOp_Q/150x150">
      <div class="bank_name" style="color:white">Sticker | JW | Cluj-Napoca 2015</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center" data-name="Sticker | DreamHack | Cluj-Napoca 2015" data-position="2" data-bot="2" data-coins="550" data-itemid="5626585817">
    <div class="bank_item" style="position:relative;border:2px solid black" data-name="Sticker | DreamHack | Cluj-Napoca 2015" data-position="2" data-bot="2" data-coins="550" data-itemid="5626585817">
      <div class="bank_bot">#2</div>
      <div class="bank_itemprice">550 coins</div>
      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXQ9QVcJY8gulReQFnaFbT8goDXW146cwFU5uP3f1Ixi_HMcm9GuN_hwIGNk6-gYuPQwDpUu5xzj-zC99Xw0BqkpRTbClhRtg/150x150">
      <div class="bank_name" style="color:white">Sticker | DreamHack | Cluj-Napoca 2015</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 text-center" data-name="Autograph Capsule | Natus Vincere | Cluj-Napoca 2015" data-position="3" data-bot="2" data-coins="480" data-itemid="5623512673">
    <div class="bank_item" style="position:relative;border:2px solid black" data-name="Autograph Capsule | Natus Vincere | Cluj-Napoca 2015" data-position="3" data-bot="2" data-coins="480" data-itemid="5623512673">
      <div class="bank_bot">#2</div>
      <div class="bank_itemprice">480 coins</div>
      <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXU5A1PIYQNqhpOSV-fROi43Z2DAghLKwVBv_T8cwYy1vWeJW5D6orildnTlq-ga-yIkzMDvJMg2bCT9tul3AWy_EVofSmtc3pMizym/150x150">
      <div class="bank_name" style="color:white">Autograph Capsule | Natus Vincere | Cluj-Napoca 2015</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

And with the sorting function:

```
$('#orderBy').on('change',function(){
    var by = $(this).val();
    switch (by){
        case '1':
            tinysort('#items .col-sm-2',{data:'coins',order:'desc'})
          break
        case '2': 
            tinysort('#items .col-sm-2',{data:'coins',order:'asc'})
          break
        case '3': 
            tinysort('#items .col-sm-2',{data:'name',order:'asc'})
          break
        default:
            tinysort('#items .col-sm-2',{data:'position',order:'asc'})
    }
});
function tinysort(target, type){
  var arr = $(target);
  arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    var x = $(a).data(type.data);
    var y = $(b).data(type.data);

    if(x > y) {
        return type.order=='asc'? 1:-1;
    } else if(x < y) {
        return  type.order=='asc'? -1:1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
  });
  $('#items').html(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are getting your data, but I would suggest trying [bootstrap tables](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/). It makes it look nice and goes well with pulling data and can sort it for you too. The [examples](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/) are also helpful if you want to look at it.

Comment: I use them in many places, but I don't need a table. I need to have seperate boxes instead. I will add a picture of how it looks at the moment.